# groupby between dates in timestamp and filtering checking another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of products for which I have their inputs and outputs. And I want to do a sliding window of 30 minutes to see if a product got in and out in those 30 minutes. I was thinking in using groupby and then filter those groups to only get the ones that they have the in(1) and out(0).

But maybe there is a better way to do it that I didn't think of.

Example:

```
    code      timestamp                   in_out
0   104       2018-12-18 16:15:00         1
1   105       2018-12-18 16:15:00         1
2   105       2018-12-18 16:35:00         0
3   107       2018-12-19 16:15:00         1
4   104       2019-01-13 10:00:00         0
5   502       2018-12-18 16:15:00         0
```

**Edit:**

The code I talked about groupby is:

```
time1 = df.iloc[0]['timestamp']
time1end = time1 + timedelta(minutes=30)
grp1 = df[(df['timestamp'] >= time1) & (df['timestamp'] <= time1end)]
grp1.groupby(by='subject_code').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

Comment: can you provide the piece of code with groupby that you are talking about?

Comment: @Laleh I posted it at Edit on the post, I didn't post it before because I think is wrong because is again the same problem, how to group the 0 and 1 of 'in_out'.

Comment: why are you grouping by time then? shouldn't we look at each code and see if they come in and then out, if the time difference is less than 30 mins?

Comment: Because I have to do a formula to see in those 30 minutes how many products got in and out, so I thought it was better to see by time, doing the formula, and check the next 30minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you do it like this:

make sure that the timestamp is the format of datetime

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Then take the codes that happened in and out (if you are sure every code was repeated exactly two times you can skip this step)

```
df2 = df.groupby('code').filter(lambda x: x['in_out'].mean()==0.5)
```

I filtered with mean==0.5 meaning once in once out, you might replace it with something smarter
Now, let's solve the problem

```
df3 = df2.groupby('code')['timestamp'].diff().dropna()
```

What this piece of code does, for each code it calculates the time difference then you can take the ones less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Although there is a problem with `df.groupby('code').filter(lambda x: x['in_out'].mean()==0.5)` because it only gets the rows with same timestamp. So from 10k rows that I had, now I only have 22. And the 2 rows with code 0 and 1 has the same timestamp

Comment: I am not sure If I got your problem. df.groupby('code').filter(lambda x: x['in_out'].mean()==0.5) doesn't keep the rows with same timestamp. If you run it on the dataframe you give as an example you will have this 0   104 2018-12-18 16:15:00       1
1   105 2018-12-18 16:15:00       1
2   105 2018-12-18 16:35:00       0
4   104 2019-01-13 10:00:00       0

Comment: Then I suppose I something else wrong that I did with the dataframe.